# Capture Cron Job parameters in a unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I have a specific requirement in my project.

The requirement is if there is cron job like the one showed below with some parameters.

When I run this script from a cron job, then these parameters that are passed on to the cron job should be captured by the called shell script and stored in somewhere(like a cassandra table) for audit purposes.

```
15 13 * * * bash /apps/LoyaltyJ4U/integration/hadoop_script/emju/script/job_single_step.sh -t=household_shopped_store -c=com.safeway.app.emju.mapreduce.job.OrcCassandraObjectMigrationJob -r=4
```

Since I am new to scripting, I am not sure how to go about with this.

Any ideas will be helpful

Thank you!

**Update** :

I have used the below command to capture the script name along with the arguments passed to it and is working fine.

```
CRON_ARG="${0##*/} $@"
```

Comment: Why don't put this parameters inside the job_single_step.sh?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the parameters with

```
echo "$0 called with params $*" > /tmp/priyanka.tmp
```

Comment: That won't be very good for audit if the server clears `/tmp` at reboot.

Comment: @Mark Correct, I am just showing how to get the information that he wants to write "somewhere (like a cassandra table)". It also overwrites a previous file. I did not not use `>> $HOME/mylog`, since he might start testing with the schedule `* * * * *` and forget to remove the entry.

Comment: I have tried     CRON_ARG="${0##*/} $@" and this is is working. So I am able to output the script name along with the arguments passed to it.